# Validation Rule with an IF

Tags: validation-rule

I need a logic: if a Contact has the same Postal Code of the related Account his insertion has to be denied. Moreover, if the Contact doesn't have an associated Account, he can have any Postal Code.

`IF ( ISBLANK( Account.ShippingPostalCode ) , MailingPostalCode ='thisCANNOTmatch', MailingPostalCode <> Account.ShippingPostalCode)`

It works but I dont think this is the proper way to work.
WHat do I have to insert in the place of

```
MailingPostalCode ='thisCANNOTmatch'
```

?

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
AND(
   NOT(ISBLANK(Account.ShippingPostalCode)),
   NOT(ISBLANK(MailingPostalCode)),
   MailingPostalCode = Account.ShippingPostalCode
)
```

if both are not blank and if both are same, then show an error..